# How can I resize canvas in a Photoshop CC animation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I've made my first animation using Photoshop CC (2018).
But my canvas is way to big. If I reduce the canvas some elements simply disappears.

Is there a way to reduce / crop the canvas without affecting my animations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- Create a new document with the new canvas size
- In this new document> **Timeline Panel** > **Create a Frame Animation**
- Back to the original document, select all the animation frames
- **Timeline Panel Menu** > **Copy All Frames**
- Go to the new document, select the animation frame
- **Timeline Panel Menu** > **Paste Frames** > Choose Replace or Over

*Note: be careful if there are layers with unlocked mask, these will be not copied. If the animation has many layers, you can do it in parts, pasting over the same frames.*

Comment: Thanks. Going from video to frames (and back again) wasn't the best option - so I just deleted my key frames, moved my objects and cropped the canvas.